# Prevent PWA service worker to be downloaded, from a different javascript file in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I guess that many people will consider that proposing restrictions for a PWA to be downloaded could not be a good strategic idea but in this concrete project I would need to been able to accomplish exactly that.
I would like to be sure that the user has registered before downloading the PWA and I think the way to go would be to automatically prevent 'service worker' to be downloaded and, when detecting user has been registered, allow it to be downloaded.
I would need to block the service worker registering process form a different file that the one that handles it. While I'm using wordpress and SuperPWA plugin I don't want to change code inside the plugin
I supose my goal would be to block somehow this function

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register(superpwa_sw.url)
```

Due to the wordpress specifications it seems that the .js files of the PWA plugin is loaded before the file from where I would like to write the blocking function.

Any clue that could point me in the right direction would be very welcome, thanks!

Comment: Well, you could serve the JS file via some PHP script which checks the cookies and refuses to output the file unless the user is registered. But what are you really trying to protect here? Why does it matter that the service worker is installed? Simply whatever your service worker *does* should only work with a user account, and that can be checked elsewhere than at the installation stage.

Comment: Hi @deceze, if I think it matters the fact that the service worker is installed because the downloading process of the PWA itself only starts when the browser detects that both service worker and manifest.json are available. I imagined that blocking one of them could work in order to make the PWA dowloadable when needed.

Comment: I know one possibility is to check in a db if the user has an account and then offer different information depending on the query, but as an importanty funcionality of my PWA would need to work offline, it doesn't seem to make sense to need a connection before using it.
That's the reason I would prefer to make it only installable when user has an account.

Comment: Did you ask the SuperPWA developers for help? Client-side Javascript hacks probably aren't secure.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably prevent the sendout of the PWA in php, in a little bit of code, with [wp_dequeue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_script/).

```php
function no_pwa_unless_logged_in() {
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
             wp_dequeue_script( 'superpwa-register-sw' );
        }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'no_pwa_unless_logged_in' );
```

The [wp_print_scripts action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_print_scripts/) fires just before sending enqueued scripts to the browser page. This code removes the PWA script from the queue.

This is a good approach: it won't allow your PWA script to go to any not-logged-in visitor, so those visitors won't have any access to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that seems to work.

Unregistering the service worker from another .js file is possible once you re-register it. This way you can get the result of the registering function and use it onwards for unregistering it.
Then I can register it again when I check the user is registered and the pwa turns downloable according to it.

```
function unregServiceWorker(){
    if(navigator.serviceWorker){
        if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
          navigator.serviceWorker
            .register(superpwa_sw.url)
            .then((registration) => {
              // registration worked
              console.log("Registration succeeded.");
              registration.unregister().then((boolean) => {
              });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error(`Registration failed with ${error}`);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried the solution of @O.jones and it works perfectly. As he says in his comment, this solution seems to be more secure. I changed the function a bit, now it doesn't only de-register it, but it also registers the script when needed, so I call the function in the header.php and again once detected the user is logged in.

```
function no_pwa_unless_logged_in($user_logged) {
        if ( ! $user_logged ) { //este bool debe ser llamado o cuando de se logea o cuando se da de alta
          wp_dequeue_script( 'superpwa-register-sw' );
        }else{
          wp_enqueue_script( 'superpwa-register-sw' );
        }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'no_pwa_unless_logged_in' );
```